# Is it possible to create a scaffold that's executed when creating a new rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using various scaffolds for various projects.
What I want to do is create a scaffold which is used  when i create a new app

example

rails new appname --scaffold_name 
so i can have different scaffold_names (e.g. one with devise, one without devise)

How can this be done?

Comment: Is there something about the overall structure of the Rails application that you would want to generate differently, or do you want to generate models/controllers etc. differently in both the apps?

Comment: the difference is in models and controllers but that's ok with the scaffolds i have when I start from a copy of my template project.
It's mainly about the gemfile itself, and some default objects, helpers and services i want to have installed by default